# Store Date in XML tags

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a question for storing Datetime into Jaxb. Currently I have this:

**XML:**

```
<reconcile>
  <start_date>2018-04-08T11:02:44</start_date>
  <end_date>2018-04-08T11:02:44</end_date>
  <page>1</page>
</reconcile>
```

**JaxB Object:**

```
    @XmlElement(name = "start_date")
    public Date start_date;
    @XmlElement(name = "end_date")
    public Date end_date;
    @XmlElement(name = "page")
```

Should I use String for start_date and end_date or I need convert the String `2018-04-08 11:02:44` before I use JAXB? Can you share what is the best practice?

Comment: Use `LocalDate`

Comment: @LocalDate can you paste working example so I can rate it?

Comment: By the way I use MariaDB and table column Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added the JAXB for `java.time` from https://github.com/jaxb-java-time-adapters/jaxb-java-time-adapters#releases

Then annotate like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Reconcile {
    @XmlElement(name = "start_date")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeXmlAdapter.class)
    public LocalDateTime start_date;

    @XmlElement(name = "end_date")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeXmlAdapter.class)
    public LocalDateTime end_date;

    @XmlElement(name = "page")
    public int page;
}
```

*Test*

```
Reconcile reconcile = new Reconcile();
reconcile.start_date = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 4, 8, 11, 2, 44);
reconcile.end_date = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 11, 8, 11, 2, 44);
reconcile.page = 1;

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Reconcile.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
marshaller.marshal(reconcile, System.out);
```

*Output*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<reconcile>
    <start_date>2018-04-08T11:02:44</start_date>
    <end_date>2018-11-08T11:02:44</end_date>
    <page>1</page>
</reconcile>
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a mistake. I need a solution for table column type Datetime. Can you update the post please?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Then edit the question and show sample value for `<start_date>` and `<end_date>` elements.

Comment: @PeterPenzov You sure you wouldn't / shouldn't be using [*standard* XML date format](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-xmlschema11-2-20120405/datatypes.html#dateTime) ([ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)), i.e. `2018-04-08T11:02:44`? If you do, simply replace `LocalDate` with `LocalDateTime`, and `LocalDateXmlAdapter` with `LocalDateTimeXmlAdapter`.

Comment: let's use the standard XML date format. Can you please update the post?